# SQL server license has expired and I am not able to log into the server now

Tags: sql-server-2014

I need to take backup but I am not able to login due to expired license

Answer (score 0):

What is possible to do in the case:

1. Check what your SQL Server is stopped.
2. Copy mdf, ndf and ldf files for databases to some server with SQL Server with same version.
3. Attach the files.

As result, you would have full copy of data, it is near same as make backup.